# Factoring a cube expression - (Step by step)

Tags: factoring

How can I factor the following expression:

$$(a+3)^3$$

Please, step by step so I can learn.

Comment: It seems to already be factored. Can you elaborate about what you need?

Comment: It looks already factored - perhaps it's something else you want done?

Comment: I would like to backshift it, I mean, I looked it up on the internet and I found an expression like this: (a+4)(a²-4a+16)... I don't know the step-by-step to get to this form though

Answer (score 1):

As noted in the comments $(a+3)^3=(a+3)(a+3)(a+3)$ is already factored.

The expression in your comment is the factorization of a different binomial expression:
$$
a^3+4^3=(a+4)(a^2-4a+4^2)
$$

You can verify this identity simply multiplying the factors.